# How to differentiate between each checkbox element within a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I don't really know how to word this question so I am sorry if this seems a bit ambiguous. I have a situation where I am generating a bunch of check boxes within a `cfloop`. Each checkbox has the same class name of `check`, but they represent a value within a database. Originally I was hoping that I can just check to see if the checked property exists using jQuery, but that doesn't work as I'd hoped. The issue it brings is that if there is one checkbox that is checked and if I check or uncheck a different checkbox the class still returns a `true` value which makes sense logically.

Here is the ColdFusion which sets the checked value and the loop which generates the html:

```
<cfloop>   
  <cfif ContainsSic.HasSiC EQ 1 >
    <cfset CheckedResult = "checked=""checked""" >
  <cfelse>
    <cfset CheckedResult = "" >
  </cfif>

 <cfoutput>
  <tr>
   <td align="center">#Passed_CustomerName#</td>
   <td align="center">#Passed_LotNumber#</td>
   <td align="center">#Passed_SubLot#</td>
   <td align="center">#Passed_CarbonAvg#</td>
   <td align="center"><input type="button" onclick="location.href='';" value="Amend" /></td>
   <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" onclick="ajax(#Passed_CustomerID#, #Passed_LotNumber#, #Passed_SubLot#)" #CheckedResult#/></td>
   <td align="center"><a href="" target="_blank">Red Tag Page</a></td>
  </tr>
 </cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

And here is the jQuery which handles the ajax call and the checked value:

```
function ajax(CustomerID, LotNumber, SubLot) { 
    if ($("input:checkbox").is(":checked")) {  
        var Checked = true;
    } 
    else {
        var Checked = false;
    }

    var passed_data = {
        method: 'UpdateHasSiC',
        CustomerID : CustomerID,
        LotNumber: LotNumber,
        SubLot: SubLot,
        Checked: Checked
    }

    console.log(passed_data);

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'LecoXMLRead_Ajax.cfc',
      data: passed_data,
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: function(data) {

      },
      error: function(e){

      }
    })

}
```

The workflow behind this is when the page loads, it grabs values from a database which determines whether or not the checkbox should be selected. It writes the values given from the database into rows with its designated checked or unchecked checkbox. The user should then be able to alter the checkbox and when doing so, update the value within the database with a `1` or `0`. `1` representing it was checked of course.

I hope this makes sense, I can provide clarification or whatever else is needed.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add custom data attribute at checkbox and then used that attribute value to pick checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" data-customerId="#Passed_CustomerID#" onclick="ajax(#Passed_CustomerID#, #Passed_LotNumber#, #Passed_SubLot#)" #CheckedResult#/>
```

In function you can use that customer id to identify that specific checkbox.
I am considering customer id as unique value.

```
function ajax(CustomerID, LotNumber, SubLot) { 
        if ( $('[data-customerId="'+CustomerID+'"]:checkbox').is(":checked")) {  
        var Checked = true;
     } 
    else {
        var Checked = false;
    }
   }
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't even know you could add custom attributes to elements. Thank you very much!

Comment: @G.Rose -  Using the onclick attribute is depreciated in html5. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the onclick action, and change your markup/js to:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-customerid="#Passed_CustomerID#" data-lotnumber="#Passed_LotNumber#" data-sublot="#Passed_SubLot#" #CheckedResult# />
```

JS:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type="checkbox"][data-customerid]').on('click', function(e) {
        ajax($(this).data('customerid'), $(this).data('lotnumber'), $(this).data('sublot'), $(this).is(':checked'));
    });
});
</script>
```

Then you would add the checked argument to your ajax function.

(I didn't test this, so look for syntax errors. LMK and I'll correct if found.)